# How to downgrade DTS in VS SSIS project from 15.0.2000.170 to 13.0.5865.1

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have a Visual Studio SSIS project currently using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) version 15.0.2000.170 and the target SQL servers are on version 13.0.5865.1. How do I downgrade my package from 15.0.2000.170 to 13.0.5865.1?

The target SQL servers are version 2016, which is the 13.0 version. I downgraded the TargetServerVersion to SQL Server 2014, but this did not affect the version - it remained 15.0.

Also, I have yet to locate an install for this version to download to install.

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Once you set the target server version - you can then deploy that project to the target catalog instance.  If that isn't working, then we need more information on what errors/problems you are encountering.

Comment: My SSIS package needs to read Excel files from a network share drive. When running on the SQL Server, I get the following error: 

_italic_Package:Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005. An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine" Hresult: 0x80004005 Description: "The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file '\\server\folder\file.xlsx'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.". _italic__

Comment: Since my laptop has version 15.0.2000.170 and the SQL Servers use version 13.0.5865.1, we want to downgrade the version on my laptop to 13.0.5865.1 so they match, in hopes that this will resolve this problem.

Comment: That problem is not related to the version of SSDT or SSIS your are using, rather the problem appears to be that some other process has that file opened or the server does not have access to that location or to the file.

Comment: We have verified that the file is not open by another process and the service accounts being used have access to the share drive.

Comment: SSIS may be accessing the file multiple times - so the second access is failing because the first one still has the file open.